# Highcharts limit the amount of items that will be displayed in categories on the yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following chart in Highcharts, I wanted to limit the amount of items that will be displayed on the yAxis, for example 7 items, which always show the first and last items of the variable `categories`.

```js
$(function () {

var categories = ["Pos 01", "Pos 02", "Pos 03", "Pos 04", "Pos 05", "Pos 06", "Pos 07", "Pos 08", "Pos 09", "Pos 10", "Pos 11", "Pos 12", "Pos 13", "Pos 14", "Pos 15", "Pos 16", "Pos 17"];

var plan = [{x: 1534095420000, y:15},{x:1534097580000, y:14},{x:1534099020000,y:13},{x:1534119900000,y:12},{x:1534149780000,y:11},{x:1534174620000,y:10},{x:1534176420000,y:9},{x:1534189020000,y:8},{x:1534313940000,y:7},{x:1534317900000,y:6},{x:1534337700000,y:5},{x:1534373880000,y:4},{x:1534374120000,y:3},{x:1534375560000,y:2},
{x:1534377720000,y:1},{x:1534378200000,y:0},{x:1534378200000,y:0},{x:1534414200000,y:0},{x:1534414620000,y:1}];

var series =[{
                name: "Plan",
                id: "plan",
                data: plan
            }];
            
          
  // Create the chart
  window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container',{
                colors: ["#7cb5ec"],
                chart: {
                    type: "spline",
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Graphic'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    categories: categories,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Position'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value}'
                    },
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Date'
                    },
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickInterval: 3600000,
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        findNearestPointBy: 'xy',
                        marker: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    split: false,
                    useHTML: true,
                    style: {
                        pointerEvents: 'all'
                    },
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y];
                    }
                },
                "series": series
            });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 600px; min-width: 500px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in many ways depending on a few things:
- what data do you have,
- how many ticks do you want to have,
- whether you want to display labels between ticks or on ticks,
- how do you want to display labels if a number of categories is not divisible by a number of ticks,
- whether you want to have equal gaps between ticks etc.

We can play with formatter function, categories, tickAmount property, yAxis.max property and many other things. But in most cases we will have to give up from setting categories ridigly.

One of examples:

I set yAxis.max

```
chart: {
  type: "spline",
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        max = chart.series[0].dataMax;

      chart.update({
        yAxis: {
            max: max
        }
      });
    }
  }
},
```

I set tickAmount to 6 and used formatter function

```
yAxis: {
  //categories: categories,
  title: {
    text: 'Position'
  },
  tickAmount: 6,
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        var value = this.value + 1;
                if (this.value < 9) {
        return 'Pos 0' + value;
      } else {
        return 'Pos ' + value;
      }
    }
  }
},
```

And I formatted tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
  split: false,
  useHTML: true,
  style: {
    pointerEvents: 'all'
  },
  formatter: function() {
    var y = this.y + 1;
    if (y < 10) {
      return 'Pos 0' + y;
    } else {
      return 'Pos ' + y;
    }
  }
},
```

[js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dao0ec3m/)

I know that the last tick is not the last element of your category array, but it would be easier to "edit" your data and work on proper data than try to adapt ticks to your strange category array and data that doesn't fit categories.

Comment: This doesn't work, because "Pos XX" is only the name I put in the example, the true name can be anything.

Comment: Then you should add some extra information. I've already told you that it can be done in many ways depending on many conditions. Give me some more information and I will be happy to answer your question more precisely and properly. Can we change your category array? Can we change data? How many ticks do you want to have? How many points will your chart have?

Comment: My category array comes from backend application and can be 10, 15, ou maybe 50 position, don´t has a limit. Think the categories are cities and
the graph is a city route by time. I want choise many ticks I need,  in this example was 7, but one day can be 10.

Comment: Well... the problem is that the number of categories may not fit a number of points and number of ticks. If you want to set categories from your array, the chart will not fit proper point's value to categories, because the value is a number type and category is a string type. Furthermore, when you set categories, you can't use a tickAmount property, but you can use a tickInterval property to show every n category.

Comment: summarizing: unfortunately, we can't do much until we know exactly what data and what categories will you get from the backend. Answering your specify question, to show first and last element of categories array, use this code https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lpq49uwn/ and play with tickInterval property, but it won't always fit to others values.

Comment: May you change your answer to the last fiddle? The last fiddle helped me, if you do this I can accept the answer